# Need to extract data from this JSON in Jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I have to extract all the "uniqueid" from this JSON array in Jmeter and then store these values in an array so that later I can use it with for each controller to append to the tail of another URL.

Can anyone help me how to do this in Jmeter.

Your help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
{"groups":[
{
  "categoryid": 4003,
  "name": "Agarbatti",
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "Take Photo",
      "type": "image",
      "displaytype": "image",
      "mandatory": false,
      "uniqueid": "1149"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "categoryid": 4005,
  "name": "Cigarettes",
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "Take Photo",
      "type": "image",
      "displaytype": "image",
      "mandatory": false,
      "uniqueid": "1150"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "categoryid": "1001",
  "name": "Remark",
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "Remark",
      "type": "string",
      "displaytype": "edit",
      "uniqueid": "Remarks",
      "mandatory": "true"
    }
  ]
    }
  ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use [JSONPath Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) (you'll need Extras with Libs Set).

So on your data following JSONPath Expression:

```
$..uniqueid
```

Will return next structure:

```
["1149","1150","Remarks"]
```

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide (scroll down to "Parsing JSON") for more details and a kind of JSONPath cookbook.